# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE_FORMAT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, junit, mariadb

I'm getting the error  below while running Junit for the hibernate class I made... 
So far whatever I googled, I found that I need to set sql.syntax_mys=true for db connection for Junit . But it doesn't work.

```
datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:data-test;sql.syntax_mys=true;shutdown=false
```

I have Maria DB, I could not find any compatible value in hsqldb for Maria db so I used MySQL syntax sql.syntax_mys=true.

Can someone please help me fix this?

My query in hibernate class is below:

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "select avg(availability) as wiActual
     from SlaDropPoint
     where year = DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y')
       and client ='All'
       and str_to_date(concat(CONVERT(year,CHAR),CONVERT(month,CHAR)), '%Y%m')
         !=str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(), '%b-%Y'),'%b-%Y')");
```

My test case is:

```
@Test
@Transactional(transactionManager="itlmTransactionManager")
public void testGetDashboardData() {

     double result = availabilityDAO.getDashboardData();

     assertNotNull(result);

}
```

It has already created data for this table @before this method call . And Junit works fine if I write simple query like select avg(availability) as wiActual from SlaDropPoint where year ='2016'

So it has problem with functions I used but how to ignore them I can't change the query.

Any pointer/help will be appreciated.

```
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement  
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)  
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)  
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)  
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)  
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)  
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1928)  
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1897)  
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at com.fmr.itlm.stabilityprogramupdate.dao.hibernate.StabilityProgramUpdateAvailabilityHibernateDAO.getDashboardData(StabilityProgramUpdateAvailabilityHibernateDAO.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getDashboardData(Unknown Source)
    at com.fmr.itlm.stabilityprogramupdate.dao.StabilityProgramUpdateAvailabilityDAOTest.testGetDashboardData(StabilityProgramUpdateAvailabilityDAOTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE_FORMAT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:293)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE_FORMAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Because not exist function `DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y')` for hsqldb

Try using for hql: `to_char(mydate,'yyyy')`

In fact, you will have to write a different query for testing and for production code